# Do you know why this error is appearing? (Call to a member function formatLocalized() on null)

Tags: laravel

I have a UserController that has the index() method that should get all the past registrations in a conference by a user and for each registration get the conference details:

I have this code below to get the past and next registrations of a user in a conference:

```
 public function index(Request $request){

        $user = $request->user();

        $pastRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['conference' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('conf_end_date', '<', now());
        }])->get();

        $nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['conference' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('conf_end_date', '>', now());
        }])->get();

        return view('users.index',
            compact('user', 'pastRegistrations','nextRegistrations'));
    }
```

To show in the index.blade.php there is this foreach:

```
 @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <p  {{optional($nextRegistration->conf)->conf_start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
        <h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->conf)->title}}</h5>
        <p Registration in {{$nextRegistration->conf->created_at }}</p>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

But it appears an error with $nextRegistrations to show the results:

```
Call to a member function formatLocalized() on null
```

in

```
<?php echo e(optional($nextRegistration->conf)->conf_start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')); ?></p>
```

The issue is only:

```
   <p  {{optional($nextRegistration->conf)->conf_start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
```

With only this works:

```
<h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->conf)->title}}</h5>
            <p Registration in {{$nextRegistration->conf->created_at }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not weird that PHP errors when you try to format something that just isn't there. You basically gave the answer yourself:

> But it appears an error in the $nextRegistrations when there are no next registrations

You have to check whether `$nextRegistrations` is null or not before you attempt to call methods on it.

You can do this with PHP methods as [`is_null`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) or [`empty`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
@if(!empty($nextRegistration->conf || !empty($nextRegistration->conf->conf_start_date))
    {{ ... }}
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but with "{{!empty(($nextRegistration->conf)->conf_start_date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M'))}}" it appears "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, but still appears "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: The error still appears if there are next registrations.

Comment: Then the error is somewhere else, because it sure as hell isn't in my answer :p